# Change ringtone for contact

Tags: ringtone

Someone has planted a song on my phone when someone is calling me instead of them hearing the ringing tone. How do I remove it?

Answer (score 2):

Open the People app and view the contact you want to change the ringtone for. Hit the pencil button to edit the contact. On the edit Screen you can select a custom or default ringtone for this person.